# Setting up Squid for Specific IPs From Announced Ranges

Tags: authentication, proxy, squid

I have multiple subnet ranges attached to my Ubuntu server that I use as proxies. I currently have Squid setup, however, when setting up user:pass profiles, each profile has access to entire subnets. For instance, if I were to give someone the proxy "198.52.161.51", they could just also input "198.52.161.52" and have access to an additional IP in that subnet that I did not mean to give them access to. Is there any way to limit the access of user:pass profiles to specific IPs from the ranges attached to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use squid acl and tcp outgoing ipaddress as below in the configuration where you need to write seperate acl and tcp outgoing address for both the IPs.

```
acl ip1 myip 198.52.161.51
tcp_outgoing_address 198.52.161.51 ip1

acl ip2 myip 198.52.161.52
tcp_outgoing_address 198.52.161.52 ip2
```

By doing the above thing 198.52.161.51 will use the proxy 198.52.161.51 and 198.52.161.52 will use the proxy 198.52.161.52

You also need to have config file like below:

```
198.52.161.51 user1
198.52.161.52 user2
```

which means that user1 has access to 198.52.161.51 proxy and user2 has access to 198.52.161.52 proxy.